# Fluent NHibernate Where on Empty String

Tags: c#, sql, .net, nhibernate, fluent

I'm applying a `.Where()`-restriction on an `IQueryOver<T,T>` in FluentNH, as such:

```
.Where(x => x.Col1 == null || x.Col1 == "");
```

Which generates the following SQL:

```
WHERE (Col1 IS NULL OR Col1 = NULL)
```

How can I make NH understand that empty string means empty string?

Comment: I haven't ever seen this. Which version of NHibernate are you using? Are you sure that the code is like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your `Where` clause like this:

```
.Where(Restrictions.On<ClassType>(obj => obj.Col1).IsNull ||
       Restrictions.On<ClassType>(obj => obj.Col1).IsLike(@""))
```

Alternatively, if you're doing this on several queries you should consider creating a query extension:

```
public static class QueryExtention {
    public static IQueryOver<E, F> WhereStringIsNullOrEmpty<E, F>(this IQueryOver<E, F> query, Expression<Func<E, object>> expression) {
        var property = Projections.Property(expression);
        var criteria = Restrictions.Or(Restrictions.IsNull(property),
                                       Restrictions.Eq(property, string.Empty));
        return query.Where(criteria);
    }
}
```

Then you should be able to create something like:

```
.QueryOver<ClassType>()
.WhereStringIsNullOrEmpty(obj => obj.Col1)
```

Comment: Kay. Seems a lot more verbose. Is there any specific reason why the ORM translates `""` to `NULL`?

Comment: @AndreasEriksson Not sure about that.